# Properties of differential equation without solving the equation

Tags: calculus

Let $f$ be a function so that $f^{\prime\prime}(x) = -4f(x)$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $f(0)=f^\prime (0)=1$.

Prove that $2f(x)\sin 2x+f'(x)\cos2x=1$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, without explicitly solving for $f$.

How should I proceed from here? The things needs to be proven resemble Caucky's Mean Value Theorem but I have no clue proceeding on.

Any kind soul please help!

Comment: multiply by f' both sides and integrate.

Comment: Until now I have only learnt differentiation but not integration... is there any way to do using differentiation and those theorems in differentiation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$2f(x)\sin 2x+f'(x)\cos2x=1$$
Differentiate with respect to $x$:
$$
2f^{'}(x)\sin 2x + 4f(x)\cos 2x+f^{''}(x)\cos 2x -2f^{'}(x)\sin2x=0\to\\
4f(x)\cos 2x + f^{''}(x)\cos 2x=0\to\\
(f^{''}(x)+4f(x))\cos 2x =0
$$
We already knew from initial equation that $f^{''}(x)+4f(x)=0$.

Also, let us calculate value of expression at $x=0$:
$$
2f(0)\sin0+f^{'}(0)\cos0=1\to\\
1=1
$$
We showed that derivatives of left and right side equal for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and point where left and right side equal, hence they should be equal for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint

you will obtain
$f''f'=-4ff'$

which yields to

$(f')^2-f^2(0)=-4(f^2-f^2(0))$
and
$(f'(t))^2-1=-4f(t)^2+4$

now take the square

$4f^2\sin^2(2x)+(f')^2\cos^2(2x)+2ff'\sin(4x)=5\cos^2(2x)+2f(x)f'(x)\sin(4x)$

your formula doesn't seem correct.